# VALIDADOR POR IDADE

Tags: javascript

Olá
Não tenho muito conhecimento de javascript, desde já agradeço se alguém puder me ajudar.

Preciso criar uma página simples de validação por idade para acessar uma página, a ideia é simples:
se a pessoa nasceu antes de 2002 redireciona a página meusite_com_br/maior 
mas se ela nasceu depois de 2002 redireciona a página meusite_com_br/menor

Garimpando achei o código abaixo que fiz alguns ajustes, porém não sei como abrir as respectivas paginas meusite_com_br/menor ou meusite_com_br/maior como resultado, o resultado nesse caso são textos:  "MENOR 18" : "MAIOR DE 18"

```html
<html>
<body>
<CENTER>
<h2>Validador de Idade</h2>

<p>Digite o ano que você nasceu para acessar o site:</p>

<input id="age" value="Ex: 1990" />
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">ACESSAR SITE</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var age, voteable;
  age = Number(document.getElementById("age").value);
  if (isNaN(age)) {
    voteable = "Você não inseriu um ano válido. <BR> Exemplo: 2020";
  } else {
    voteable = (age > 2002) ? "MENOR 18" : "MAIOR DE 18";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = voteable;
}
</script>
</CENTER>
</body>
</html>
```

Novamente agradeço a ajuda!
Luis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta usar `window.location` com o endereço desejado, assim:

```
  var age = Number(document.getElementById("age").value);

  if (isNaN(age)) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Você não inseriu um ano válido. <BR> Exemplo: 2020";
  } else if (age > 2002) {
    window.location = "/menor";
  } else {
    window.location = "/maior";
  }
```

ps: não era necessário declarar as variáveis antes, poderia declarar e já setar, e no caso da variavel `voteable` nem precisa para o caso do valor ser numerico, porque já vai redirecionar, não vai nem dar muito tempo pra ler a mensagem

Comment: podia ter ajudado no `if (age > 2002)` ... para o ano tem de alterar :P -> `if(age > (new Date().getFullYear() - 18))...`

Comment: @balexandre isto vai além do que é perguntando, o problema da pergunta é o redirecionamento, não como funciona a parte lógica, mas concordo que seria uma melhora, apesar de validação front-end raramente ser uma boa, só sendo interessante para evitar requisições HTTP desnecessárias e até customizar um pouco o visual.

Comment: Guilherme e Alexandre. Agradecido, testei a alteração que o Guilherme enviou e funcionou perfeitamente, é claro que pedi o básico que tivesse a função que eu necessito e já foi perfeito, mas claro que melhorias são sempre bem vindas, por não entender muito do assunto como disse anteriormente, não consegui executar a melhoria que o Alexandre passou e claro que visualmente sei que não está bonito, mas como preciso muito de um validador que leve para caminhos diferente dependendo da resposta e esse código foi o único que consegui. Esse código peguei em w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: @Luis validação é relativo, o teu caso nem chega a ser validar, a pergunta esta mais para o uso de IFs e como redirecionar, validar seria algo mais complexo e com certeza teria que ser feito no back-end e se possivel com dados mais confiaveis do que o proprio usuario dizer o ano que nasceu, pq desta forma qualquer um pode burlar o sistema, mas de qualquer forma a pergunta é sobre ifs e redirecionamento, e acho que isto eu já respondi, se puder marcar como correta acaso tenha resolvido ficarei grato, e se tiver uma duvida nova de validação de verdade abra uma nova pergunta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sem dúvida está respondido e classificado e fico grato. Com certeza entendo que não é uma validação mas sim um aviso de conteúdo falando de forma leiga.